# RedirectToAction with Parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to call action from another action by passing parameter values. Url is adding `/category?id=1`, but I was expecting `/category/1`. Don't know why it is sending with `?id=`.

### edit:

```
 return RedirectToAction(actionName: "Index", controllerName: "Category",
                routeValues: new {id=id});



    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Admin/Category/{langID:int=0}")]
    public ActionResult Index(int langId)
    {
       --
    }
```

after redirection url is `Admin/Category?id=1`

MapRoute

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "AdminPages",
            url: "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Category", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "CategoryEdit",
            url:"Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Category", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Comment: Shouldn't you expect `/Category/Index/1` ?

Comment: you're showing us `DisplayCategories`, can you show the actual `Index` method?

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I was `/Category/Index/1` from `RedirectToAction`, is it not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your routeValues to `routeValues: new { langId = id};` to match your action signature

Comment: Now it url comes like this `/Category?langId=1`

Comment: You could build it yourself -> `Redirect("/Category/Index/"+id)`

Comment: @Jonesy, This works. But My question is MVC5, new routing suppose to not take with `?langId`.